# Does ML.Net transformations apply stopwords?

Tags: ml.net

I'm new to ML.Net and playing around with some basic MultiClassClassification scenarios and wondering if it can already handle stopwords by default now or should I do that in my data prep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [this section](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#how-do-i-train-my-model-on-textual-data) of ML.NET cookbook.

If you use `mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText` in your pipeline, it will by default remove English stopwords.

Of course, you are free to tweak your NLP preprocessing using other ML.NET provided components, but, from my little experience with text classification, the catch-all `FeaturizeText` is doing a reasonable job for most cases.